# Black lambda Magic

Tags: python, lambda, scipy

In scipy.splev I found this piece of code:

```
def splev( x, tck, int der=0, int ext=0):

    t,c,k = tck
    try:
        c[0][0]
        parametric = True
    except:
        parametric = False
    if parametric:
        return list(map(lambda c, x=x, t=t, k=k, der=der: splev(x, [t,c,k], der, ext), c ))
    else:
        .
        .
        .
    return y.reshape(shape)
```

and I fail to understand the lambda, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda function here:

```
lambda c, x=x, t=t, k=k, der=der: splev(x, [t,c,k], der, ext)
```

is the same as:

```
def anonymous_lambda_function(c, x=x, t=t, k=k, der=der):
    return splev(x, [t,c,k], der, ext)
```

and map is mapping this function to the elements of an iterable, `c`.

The `list(map(...))` is redundant in Python 2, but it's necessary in Python 3, so it preserves the code's forward compatibility.

Comment: THX for mentioning the iterable

Answer (score 0):

`lambdas` are just unnamed functions. You could write it like this:

```
def splev( x, tck, int der=0, int ext=0):

    t,c,k = tck

    def otherfxn(c, x=x, t=t, k=k, der=der):
        return splev(x, [t,c,k], der, ext)

    try:
        c[0][0]
        parametric = True
    except:
        parametric = False
    if parametric:
        return list(map(otherfxn, c))
    else:
        .
        .
        .
    return y.reshape(shape)
```

Comment: Your example bridged the theoretical knowledge to a practical example
THX